# Definition of $\underline{L}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am reading Mumford's book on Abelian Varieties and I want to how that $H^i(X,\underline{L})=0$ for all i, where $L \in Pic^o(X)$. I am wondering about the definition of $\underline{L}$ if $L$ is a sheaf.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. If $L$ is a line bundle (or more generally a vector bundle), then $\underline{L}$ means the sheaf of sections of $L$ (e.g. top of p.55 in the original edition). Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Yes, $L$ is a line bundle.Thanks.

Comment: Did I answer your question?

Comment: Yes, you did. It can see from the proof.